# Show CPU and memory usage of multiple VMs with VMWare workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 7.1.2 on Windows7 with an Intel dualcore E8400. I'm currently running three hosts, all windows XP, and my host's CPU usage is very high; often hitting 100% for a few seconds, on both of my two cores. Is there an easy way to show CPU (and memory, while I'm at it) usage of all VMs?